# Sum of exponentials with Fourier coefficient

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, fourier-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function with period $2\pi$. Define $$u(r,\theta)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty r^{|n|}\hat{f}(n)e^{in\theta}$$ for $r\in[0,1)$, where $\hat{f}(n)$ is the $n$th Fourier coefficient of $f$.

a) Express $u$ as a series in $z=x+iy$ and $\bar{z}=x-iy$.

b) Show that $u$ is infinitely differentiable in $x^2+y^2<1$.

For a), I want to substitute in $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\theta=\tan^{-1}(y/x)$. But this doesn't seem to yield a nice expression in terms of $z$ and $\bar{z}$.

For b), since this is an infinite sum, if we take the derivative term by term, we have to worry about convergence. Also, there are two variables to differentiate with respect to ($r$ and $\theta$), which makes it more complicated.

Comment: Just a guess, ... 
let $z = r e^{i \theta }$ then $\bar z = r e^{-i\theta }$, this gives, 
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (f(n) z^n + f(-(n+1)) \bar z^{n+1} )$

Comment: A remark about b/, $x^2+y^2=r^2=|z|^2$. Best regards

Comment: experimentX is correct.  Therefore, the function is $A(z) + B(\bar z)$, where $A$ and $B$ are analytic functions on $\{z:|z|<1\}$.  This is because the sequence $\hat f(n)$ is bounded, and hence the radius of convergence is $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the hint by experimentX: 
$$
u(r,\theta) = f(z)+\overline{g(z)} 
$$
where both functions
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \hat f(n) z^n\qquad  g(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \overline{\hat f(-n)} z^n$$
are holomorphic in the unit disk. The power series converge because the Fourier coefficients are uniformly bounded: this only requires $f$ to be integrable on the circle. That holomorphic functions are infinitely differentiable (their power series can be differentiated term by term) is one of basic results in complex analysis.