# Function with Fourier coefficients extend onto closed disk

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis

> Let $f$ be a continuous function with period $2\pi$. Define $$u(r,\theta)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty r^{|n|}\hat{f}(n)e^{in\theta}$$ for $r\in[0,1)$, where $\hat{f}(n)$ is the $n$th Fourier coefficient of $f$.
>
> Prove that $u$ extends to a continuous function on the closed unit disk.

We want to show that if we have a sequence $r_j\rightarrow 1^-$ and $\theta_j\rightarrow\theta$, then $u(r_j,\theta_j)$ converges to $f(\theta)$.

I can show that $\sup_\theta|u(r,\theta)-f(\theta)|\rightarrow 0$ as $r\rightarrow 1^-$. But this is converging only from one direction at a time ($\theta$ is fixed). How can we show for convergence in any direction as $r_j\rightarrow 1^-$ and $\theta_j\rightarrow\theta$?

[Note: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548763/sum-of-exponentials-with-fourier-coefficient) for a related question on this function $u$.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you can show $$\sup_\theta |u(r,\theta)-f(\theta)|\rightarrow 0,\quad   r\to 1^-\tag{1}$$  you are done.

Given $\epsilon>0$, let $\delta>0$ be such that $|f(\theta)-f(\phi)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|\theta-\phi|<\delta$. Also pick $r_0<1$ such that $|f(\theta)-u(r,\theta)|<\epsilon$ whenever $r>r_0$; this $r_0$ is provided by (1). Conclude that $|f(\theta)-u(r,\phi)|<2\epsilon$ whenever $r>r_0$ and $|\theta-\phi|<\delta$. This is what was required.